# Convert CURL Post to Python Requests Failing

Tags: python, curl, server, python-requests

I am unable to successfully convert and execute a curl post command to python code.

curl command

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8" -d '{"name":joe, "type":22, "summary":"Test"}' http://url
```

Converted code

```
import requests
import json 

url="http://url"
data = {"name":joe, "type":22, "summary":"Test"}
headers = {'Content-type': "application/json; charset=utf8"}
response  = requests.post (url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
print response.text
print response.headers
```

I get no response in return, when I execute it manually from the shell it works fine, but when I execute the code, nothing happens, I don't see errors or anything.

Comment: Yes, I just added it in the question. Nothing comes back, its empty

Comment: After modifying your code to get it to run. I successfully got a response on the following URL.

http://httpbin.org/post

I suggest you modify your example code so it is as short as is possible  while still presenting this undesired behaviour.

Also, make sure that it runs without us needing to do anything, (add the imports, remove joe variable)

This might also help you see where the problem is not in.

Comment: ok, thank you for the advice. Were you able to locate the issue?

Comment: No, because I wasn't able to reproduce it.

Comment: Try this code, it is the simplest post request possible [mcve] that works:
  import requests
  url="http://httpbin.org/post"/
  response  = requests.post (url, "hi")
  print(response.text)

Comment: Can't test this second, but `data` expects a dictionary I think. Try changing `data=json.dumps(data)` to `data=data`

Comment: I was just able to fix it. My summary field in data was something like this "summary":"this is title". I moved the text out and assigned it to a variable and it worked. "summary":var. Not sure why it didnt work earlier...

Comment: Also, your dictionary looks malformed for `headers` with the semi-colon. Change to `headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'charset': 'utf8'}`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using one of the latest versions of requests:
Try using the 'json' kwarg (no need to convert to json explicitly) instead of the 'data' kwarg:

```
response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
```

Note: Also, this way you can omit the 'Content-type' header.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have a proxy configured at your environment, define it at your session/request as well.

For example with session:

```
my_proxies = {  
'http': 'http://myproxy:8080',  
'https': 'https://myproxy:8080'  
}  

session = requests.Session()  
request = requests.Request('POST', 'http://my.domain.com', data=params_template, headers=req_headers, proxies=my_proxies)  
prepped = session.prepare_request(request)  
response = session.send(prepped)
```

see documentation:
request http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/
session http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/